# 1024 char limit on command line in emacs shell mode on OSX

Tags: osx, term, shell-mode

I am running into a 1024 character limit for a bash command line in emacs shell mode.  For example the command:

```
echo xxxxxxxxxxxxx...x
```

with 1018 x's (for a total line length of 1023 chars) works fine, echoing the x's. However with 1019 or more x's (for a total line length of 1024 or more chars) it just starts generating ^G characters, one per character over 1023, and not returning (must ^C^C out of it). It does not matter if some of those 1023 characters are spaces, so it is not an issue of argument length.

This is of course not a problem running bash outside emacs.

Is there any way to change this emacs shell limit?

(version: Aquamacs 3.2 GNU Emacs 24.4.51.2)

Comment: That's a terminal driver limit, not a bash limit, I think.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Linux, so it must be something particular to shell-mode (or maybe comint?) in OSX.